# golang.org/x/net/icmp: set Time To Live (TTL)

Tags: go, icmp

Go has built-in ICMP implementation that available on [golang.org/x/net/icmp](https://golang.org/x/net/icmp), is there any way to set TTL in this library ?, thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer from mattn code :

```golang
c.IPv4PacketConn().SetTTL(64) // for ipv4
c.IPv6PacketConn().HopLimit(64) // for ipv6
```

https://gist.github.com/mattn/7ff153fe8491a2900e83#file-ping_test-go-L24-L28